# Finding the total number of cycles and cycle length

Tags: graph-theory, cycle, depth-first-search

I am interested in finding the total number of cycles and cycles length in a connected undirected graph. Can I use DFS? Or can DFS only find a single cycle? Any code will definitely help.

Comment: What language are you working with?  And I think one of those should be BFS =)

Comment: Also, be aware that the number of cycles in a graph of moderate size can be HUGE.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following reference:

https://www.me.utexas.edu/~bard/IP/Handouts/cycles.pdf

Comment: Exactly what I posted.  I didn't get a new post notification in time, sorry.

Comment: as noted in the cited pdf: The number of cycles can be exponential in the number of nodes. Using a simple DFS, each cycle is found using one time step, resulting in exponential running time. If this becomes a problem (on a dense graph even for well less then 100 nodes), one must use a more sophisticated algorithm. I had in mind that there exist one.

Answer (score 0):

From the graph theory we know that:

1. if the quantity of vertices of a graph is more than the quantity of edges, therefore, cycles (closed contours) are absent.
2. if the quantity of vertices of a graph is equal to the quantity of edges, therefore, a graph has only one cycle.
3. if the quantity of vertices of a graph is less than the quantity of edges, therefore, a graph has more than one closed contour.

[image]

This problem can be solved, using the algorithm **Depth first search**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
const int maximumSize=40;
vector<vector<int>> visited(maximumSize, vector<int>(maximumSize, 0));
vector<int> graph[maximumSize], closedContour, temporary;
int vertices, edges;
set<vector<int>> contours;
void showContentSetVector(set<vector<int>> input)
{
    for(auto iterator=input.begin(); iterator!=input.end(); ++iterator)
    {
        for(auto item : *iterator)
        {
            cout<<item<<", ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    return;
}
bool compare(int i,int j)
{
    return (i<j);
}
void createGraph()
{
    cin>>vertices>>edges;
    int vertex0, vertex1;
    for(int i=1; i<=edges; ++i)
    {
        cin>>vertex0>>vertex1;
        graph[vertex0].push_back(vertex1);
        graph[vertex1].push_back(vertex0);
    }
    return;
}
void depthFirstSearch(int initial, int current, int previous)
{
    if(visited[initial][current]==1)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<temporary.size(); ++i)
        {
            if(temporary[i]==current)
            {
                for(int j=i; j<temporary.size(); ++j)
                {
                    closedContour.push_back(temporary[j]);
                }
            }
        }
        sort(closedContour.begin(), closedContour.end(), compare);
        contours.insert(closedContour);
        closedContour.clear();
        return;
    }
    visited[initial][current]=1;
    temporary.push_back(current);
    for(int next : graph[current])
    {
        if(next==previous)
        {
            continue;
        }
        depthFirstSearch(initial, next, current);
    }
    temporary.pop_back();
    return;
}
void solve()
{
    createGraph();
    for(int vertex=1; vertex<=vertices; ++vertex)
    {
        temporary.clear();
        depthFirstSearch(vertex, vertex, -1);
    }
    cout<<"contours <- ";
    showContentSetVector(contours);
    return;
}
int main()
{
    solve();
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the result:

```
contours <- 
1, 2, 3, 4, 
6, 7, 8,
```